# Do I need client or server cert for mySQL master/master replication?

Tags: mysql, ssl, certificate, master-master-replication

WE use *pkitool* to sign any certificate using our own CA and there are two options to sign a certificates:

1. using `--sign`, which creates a client-cert
2. Using `--server`, which creates a server-cert

The difference between those two are in ***X509v3 Extended Key Usage***. For #1, it says `TLS Web Client Authentication` whilst the latter says: `TLS Web Server Authentication`. My question is: which particular type of cert(s) do I need to do a encrypted master-master replication?

I went through various replications guides but none mention about the type specifically or used the term 'master' and 'client' interchangeably. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!!

-S

Comment: master-master replication is really master-slave in both directions (and can mean multiple things, its not for the beginner, there are traps). In each case the certs are specified differently for master and slave. AFAIK there's no major constrains on key attributes, mainly that both are issued of the same CA, and the domain / SAN is correct.

Comment: Thanks @danblack